# CodeIgniter - Select data from db, common to all views

Tags: codeigniter, view

I'm very new to CI. :)

In my project, I have separated the page into header, footer and body. And the body portion(view) is loaded based on the controller. The header and footer are common to all pages.

For example, for a login page it would be like this:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('login');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

But now my concern is, how to generate the "category" section (which will list several category names on the left of the body portion). Upon clicking a category, the corresponding details page would be show to the right(ie. in content portion). So, in all views(all pages) I need to display the list of categories.

Visual example:

```
----------------------------
   Header Portion of Page
----------------------------
       Body Portion
       ============
Cat1 |
Cat2 |
Cat3 |     Content
Cat4 |
Cat5 |
----------------------------
          Footer
----------------------------
```

These categories are populated from the data in db.

I have just done some searching. So, I am thinking about creating a helper class and autoload it. So, in all views, I would call the function and and echo the result.

For eg:

```
function hlp_getCategories()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $q = $ci->db->query('SELECT cat_name FROM tblCategories');
            return $q;
}
```

And in the view:

```
<?php
$q = hlp_getCategories();
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo anchor('cat/' . $row['cat_name'], $row['cat_name']) ;
}
?>
```

Is this the correct approach ?
Am I in the right track ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one way to solve it - although if you follow a strict MVC approach - the helper would call the model $this->category->select_cat(), and put the SQL query in the model. Furthermore, the SQL query should use active record selections, not a text SQL query.

The other way to solve it is to use some CSS that has a DIV for the left menu (i.e. categories), and a DIV for the right (i.e. content).

Then you could do

```
 $this->load->view('header'); 
 $this->load->view('categories');
 $this->load->view('login'); 
 $this->load->view('footer');
```

Then inside your categories view

```
 <div class = "left">
     // show categories here
 </div>
```

and inside your content views

```
  <div class = "right">
     // show content here
 </div>
```